# SQL Server 2012 WKT differs from OGC specification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, standards, wkt, ogc

It is said that SQL Server is following OGC standards. In SQL Server 2012 **WKT** representation of a 2D point (e.g. 10,10) with measure value (e.g. 40) is like this:

```
"POINT (10 10 NULL 40)"
```

however in [OGC](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa) it is defined as follow:

```
"Point M (10 10 40)"
```

Why?